# How to pass a variable from clicked element to DialogBox

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

This is my code :

```js
$(function(){
    $( "#dialogLoad" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
               modal: true,
               title: 'DATE REELLE CHARGEMENT',
               width: 300,
               buttons: {
                  OK: function() {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var regdate = /^(([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/[2][0]\d{2})$|^(([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/[2][0]\d{2}\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])\:[0-5]\d\:[0-5]\d)$/;
                    //alert($('#dateReelleChargement').val());
                    if(!regdate.test($('#dateReelleChargement').val()))
                    {                       
                        $('#errLoad').text("La date doit être au format jj/mm/aaaa");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Here AJAX
                        alert("Here i would like to display loaded_383")
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                  }
               },
            });
            $( ".loaded" ).click(function() {
               $( "#dialogLoad" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
         });
```

```html
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div><a id="loaded_383" class="loaded" href="#">Test</a></div>
  
<div id ="dialogLoad">
    <p>Vous devez entrer une date de chargement réel</p>
    <input type="hidden" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <input id="dateReelleChargement" type="text" /><br /><br />
    <div id="errLoad" style="color: red;"></div>
</div>
```

For my ajax request, I will need ID of the clicked element :

```
$(".loaded")
```

How can I do to pass the variable :

```
$(this).attr('id)
```

In the dialog parameters? Indeed, 'this' can't work in the first function because it conerns the dialogBox and not the element where i clicked.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and create a [mcve]

Comment: You can find my edited post with the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better solution without using a global variable. You can set .data() on the dialog and pass your data through that. Hope this helps.

```js
$(function(){
    $( "#dialogLoad" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
               modal: true,
               title: 'DATE REELLE CHARGEMENT',
               width: 300,
               buttons: {
                  OK: function() {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var regdate = /^(([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/[2][0]\d{2})$|^(([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/[2][0]\d{2}\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])\:[0-5]\d\:[0-5]\d)$/;
                    //alert($('#dateReelleChargement').val());
                    if(!regdate.test($('#dateReelleChargement').val()))
                    {                       
                        $('#errLoad').text("La date doit être au format jj/mm/aaaa");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Here AJAX
                        alert($(this).data('passedID'));
                        alert("Here i would like to display loaded_383")
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                  }
               },
            });
            $( ".loaded" ).click(function() {
               $( "#dialogLoad" )
                   .data('passedID', $(this).attr('id'))
                   .dialog( "open" );
            });
         });
```

```html
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div><a id="loaded_383" class="loaded" href="#">Test</a></div>
  
<div id ="dialogLoad">
    <p>Vous devez entrer une date de chargement réel</p>
    <input type="hidden" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <input id="dateReelleChargement" type="text" /><br /><br />
    <div id="errLoad" style="color: red;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution !! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

You can just define a variable outside of the $(function() { ... }) and use it inside.

```js
var id;
$(function(){
    $( "#dialogLoad" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
               modal: true,
               title: 'DATE REELLE CHARGEMENT',
               width: 300,
               buttons: {
                  OK: function() {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var regdate = /^(([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/[2][0]\d{2})$|^(([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/[2][0]\d{2}\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])\:[0-5]\d\:[0-5]\d)$/;
                    //alert($('#dateReelleChargement').val());
                    if(!regdate.test($('#dateReelleChargement').val()))
                    {                       
                        $('#errLoad').text("La date doit être au format jj/mm/aaaa");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Here AJAX
                        alert(id);
                        alert("Here i would like to display loaded_383")
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                  }
               },
            });
            $( ".loaded" ).click(function() {
               id = $(this).attr('id');
               $( "#dialogLoad" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
         });
```

```html
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div><a id="loaded_383" class="loaded" href="#">Test</a></div>
  
<div id ="dialogLoad">
    <p>Vous devez entrer une date de chargement réel</p>
    <input type="hidden" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <input id="dateReelleChargement" type="text" /><br /><br />
    <div id="errLoad" style="color: red;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok... I should think about it before... Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just store the id to a variable. That way you dont have to depend on the 'this' object.

instead of:

```
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

try:

```
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Then use it when you get to the ajax code. In the worst case, you could even make the variable global.

Comment: If I store the id into a variable, then I have to set this variable as public one. Because, the variable stays in its function... Moreover, how can i make it public when I need its value when clicking? (the elements with the same class are numerous !